# KML import doesn't work

Tags: qgis, kml

I found data about offshore Windparks in Germany I'd like to import into QGIS. 
According to this tutorial it should be quite easy:

http://www.igismap.com/convert-kml-shapefile-qgis/

But all I get are empty layers. The attribute table is empty too.

The dataset is downloaded from here:

http://www.geoportal.de/DE/Geoportal/Karten/karten.html?lang=de&wmcid=111

I download the Windfarm data under ''Speichern'' and I get a small 5,5kb file. Importing it into QGIS works technicially but the layer is empty.

Comment: Does GoogleEarth show downloaded file properly? Can you provide the kml file.

Answer (score 3):

The kml file I get is just a wrapper around a WMS layer, when added to QGis I get a bounding box but zooming in doesn't seem to generate more requests.

However pasting `https://www.geoseaportal.de/wss/service/CONTIS_Facilities/guest?` into the QGis WMS server box seems to work just fine.